form validation required attribute triggered before I submit my form in Reactjs
I have an form and with multiple TextFields from Mui , And i create a reusable Select box component for my project and I texted 2 code files
I have 2 text fields with required attribute In form , in form submission onSubmit function it goes to store at db and I set e.preventDefault();
So my problem is
If I directly go to click select Box it shows "Please fill in this field"
on fields but I didn't even submit the form ,
It only happens when I click the select Box .
So now I completed the first required field of username and I have another one which is phone field so for now I leave phone field and goes to chose select Box and it shows "Please fill in this field" on phone field before submitting the form
But even it shows that , the select Box is opened and shows the option values ......Thank u in advance
Main File
const menuItems = ['val1', 'val2'];

function SavingDetails(e) {
    if (typeof (e) === 'string' && !e.target) { 
        // Handling case for select box returning value directly , like if chose value it returns value directly                                     o it doesnt have e.target , Like it returns val1 or val2 or none
        
return setUserDetails((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            profession: e
        }));
    }
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUserDetails((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [name]: value
    }));
}

<div id="content-div">
<form>
    <label htmlFor="nameid">Name</label>
    <TextField 
        required 
        onChange={SavingDetails} 
        value={userDetails.username} 
        id="nameid" 
        name="username" 
        type="text" 
    />
</div>

<div id="content-div">
    <label htmlFor="num">Phone</label>
    <TextField 
        required 
        onChange={SavingDetails} 
        value={userDetails.userphone} 
        id="num" 
        name="userphone" 
        type="phone" 
    />
</form>
</div>

<SelectBox 
    onChange={SavingDetails} 
    selectBoxWidth="80%" 
    placeHolder="Choose"
>
    <MenuItem value="None">None</MenuItem>
    {menuItems.map((val, ind) => (
        <MenuItem value={val} key={ind}>{val}</MenuItem>
    ))}
</SelectBox>

Select Box and Menu item Re-usable component file jsx
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, Children, cloneElement, useCallback } from "react";

export function MenuItem({ value, children, onSelect, isSelected }) {
    return (
        <button
            type="button"
            value={value}
            onClick={() => onSelect(value)}
            className={isSelected ? 'active-dd-btn' : ''}
        >
            {children}
        </button>
    );
}

export function SelectBox({ placeHolder = 'Placeholder..', children, onChange }) {
    const selectRef = useRef(null);
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("");

    const HandleChange = useCallback(
        (value) => {
            onChange(value);
            setSelectedValue(value);
            setOpen(false);
        },
        [onChange]
    );

    function openDropDown() {
        setOpen(!isOpen);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickAway = (event) => {
            if (selectRef.current && !selectRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
                setOpen(false);
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickAway);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickAway);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div onChange={onChange} ref={selectRef}>
            <button onClick={openDropDown}>
                {selectedValue === undefined || selectedValue === '' ? placeHolder : selectedValue}
            </button>
            {isOpen && (
                <div id="dropdown">
                    {Children.map(children, (child) =>
                        cloneElement(child, {
                            onSelect: HandleChange,
                            isSelected: child.props.value === selectedValue
                        })
                    )}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}


When you click the SelectBox, the browser sees it as an interaction with a form control, causing the built-in validation to kick in and display "Please fill in this field" for any required fields that are still empty.

To resolve this issue please Prevent Form Validation on SelectBox Interaction
  function openDropDown(event) {
     event.preventDefault();  setOpen(!isOpen);
  }


Another solution is to Disable Native Form Validation by adding noValidate in form tag
 <form noValidate onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>




Thank u so much I applied your first solution as e.preventDefault() , Thank u

Welcome! Is your issue resolved ? If yes then can you please accept my answer.

i don't have reputation to upvote u r answer
